# Confirm Dialog cuando vas a cerrar una ventana de navegador

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Hola pues mi duda es como puedo hacer para que me salga un mensaje de dialogo cuando un usuario quiere cerrar la pagina para que confirmen si quieren salir o quieren permanecer en el sitio, probé de muchas formas que vi por otros posts y ninguna me funciona, muchas gracias

```
 xmlhttp.open("POST","LogoutAction",false); //esta es una de ellas.
```

y otra seria a través de un onbeforeunload pero tampoco me funciona

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
      var message = 'Sure you want to leave?';
      if (typeof event == 'undefined') {
        event = window.event;
      }
      if (event) {
        event.returnValue = message;
      }
      return message;
    };

    $(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
    var x =logout();
    return x;
    });
    function logout(){
            jQuery.ajax({
            });
            return 1+3;
    }
```

estoy probando asi y solo me funciona en firefox

Answer (score 1):

El funcionamineto básico es el siguiente:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return 'You have unsaved changes!';
}
```

Como eventlistener:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.returnValue = '';
});
```

Con Jquery:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
  return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
});
```

Dicha función te permite ejecutar código dentro si quieres lanzar algún proceso (aunque es un poco limitado su uso).
Pero el retorno de un string, no sirve de nada, el navegador no mostrará tu mensaje sino, el que tiene el browser por default. Eso sí, Chrome require que returnValue tenga un valor (así sea vacío).

Comment: Y ese codigo va en el head del index? Porque funciona solo dentro de mi aplicacion cuando cambia de ventana, pero no al cerrar la pestaña o algo

Comment: Este código debe ejecutarse con Javascript. Puede ser entre tags de script en el <head>, dentro del <body> o bien en un archivo *.js .. Cual usar? depende de tu código, de si quieres o no cumplir con los estandares o bien, relacionado a tiempos de carga.

Answer (score 0):

Yo te recomiendo la de onbeforeunload y que pruebes con otros navegadores. Te adjunto el código del mismo.

Código:

```
<script>
  $(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
    var x =logout();
    return x;
  });
  function logout(){
    jQuery.ajax({
    });
    return 1+3;
  }
</script>
```

A la hora de salir o dar a un enlace que te lleva a otra página, te mostrará este mensaje.

[image: Aviso]

Comment: Hola Sergio muchas gracias pero esa ya la habia probado en todos los nagadores y en ninguno me funcionaba, estoy creando una aplicación en php y me haría falta eso para que los usuarios no la cerraran sin querer al cerrar el navegador o darle para atrás mientras la usan para que no pierdan los datos que no hayan guardado

Comment: Dejame hacer unas pruebas y te actualizo el mensaje

Comment: Tras esperar unos segundos, a la hora de cerrar la ventana te sale un aviso. Lo he probado con Firefox. @RubénDominguezRivera

Comment: Eso lo metes dentro de un bloque php o dentro de etiquetas <script>??? por que a mi no me funciona yo lo estoy metiendo entre etiquetas script @SergioAraque

Comment: Lo he puesto justo antes de cerrar el html entre etiquetas <script>

Comment: en firefox si que funciona pero en los demas no

Comment: el rollo es que aqui cada usuario usa el navegador que le da la gana he ahi el problema

Comment: Te he puesto uno nuevo que me ha funcionado tanto en Chrome como en Firefox

Comment: vale voy a hacer la prueba y te digo: chrome no lo pilla, firefox si

Comment: puedo recomendarles a los usuarios usar firefox pero como se que no van a hacer ni caso a ver si encuentro una solución que funcione en todos los navegadores

Comment: Que raro, a mi me lo coge en Firefox, Chrome y Opera. Prueba a copiarlo ahora literalmente antes de que cierres el </html>

Comment: ya me parece raro que a ti te funcione y a mi no igual estoy poniendo algo mal

Comment: microsoft edge e internet explorer funciona tambien pero en chrome no probe a borrar el cache del navegador y sigue sin ir pero bueno por lo menos funciona @SergioAraque

Comment: Prueba abriendolo en una ventana de incógnito por si acaso y dale unos segundos a la web.

Comment: lo que ahora tengo es un problema por que tengo recarga automatica cuando introducen algun tipo de dato para que se hagan algunas operaciones y cuando realiza esos refrescos me salta tambien el mensaje

Comment: en modo incognito si que me funciona

Comment: Se me ocurre que establezcas una booleana para cuando hagas operaciones y en el código que te puse, ponerla como un if. Así cuando acabe la operación, el booleano vuelve a su estado original. Y con el problema, si ha sido resuelto, marca la cruz verde para ayudar a la comunidad :D

Comment: No entiendo a que te refieres yo lo que hago en un onchange="form1.submit()" y ahi es cuando me salta el error lo que puedo hacer es meter todo el body en una sentencia if para que no me lo haga nunca si refresco desde ahi o incluso en un bucle while

Comment: Esa idea es incluso mejor de la que yo he pensado.